# How to inflate a ViewStub using ViewBinding in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-android-extensions, android-viewbinding

As Kotlin Synthetics is deprecated, we are migrating to ViewBinding.

I have tried a lot of googling and reading documentation on ViewStub, ViewBinding and have implemented ViewBinding for Fragments Activities, include, merge tags however I could not find any way to inflate the ViewStub using ViewBinding.

```
 <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/viewStubLayout"
            tools:layout="@layout/view_demo_layout" />
```

Please ignore the width and height attributes for this they were added as a style and have been removed from this snippet.

Can you please share how to inflate this view with another xml layout dynamically using ViewBinding.

Even in the ViewStub.java file, the class level comments state that,

> The preferred way to perform the inflation of the layout resource is
> the following:
>
> ```
> ViewStub stub = findViewById(R.id.stub);
> View inflated = stub.inflate();
> ```

Does this mean that,  I have to keep using R.layout.xxx_xx to inflate the viewstub. Can't I use the binding object for that particular xml file to inflate the view ?

Comment: Inflation will be like that only `stub.inflate()` . If you want binding object the you can get it  by `DataBindingUtil.bind(inflated)`.

Comment: @ADM The question is that instead of using R.layout.stub here in this line : ViewStub stub = findViewById(R.id. view_demo_layout);
Can I use the binding class that would be generated : ViewDemoLayoutBinding ?

Comment: also, what is DataBindingUtil ? I a not using DataBinding. I am using ViewBinding.

Comment: Its the same thing you can call `ViewDemoLayoutBinding.bind()` on your binding class instead of DataBindingUtil .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[I wrote](https://betterprogramming.pub/exploring-viewbinding-in-depth-598925821e41?source=friends_link&sk=463fd1303047ab6e2b0c2286bf6fe845) about `ViewBinding` when it was in Beta. I covered every case except `ViewStub`. `ViewStub` case is fairly similar to the case of `<Include>` in my linked article.
What you have to do is call `bind()` function of your `ViewStub` layout and pass the root where you added `ViewStub`. Remember to call `bind()` in `setOnInflateListener`.

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
private var binding: FragmentMainBinding by autoCleared()
private var stubBinding: StubBinding by autoCleared()

  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
      binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
      binding.stub.setOnInflateListener { _, inflateId -> stubBinding = StubBinding.bind(inflateId) }
      return binding.root
  }

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
      binding.stub.inflate()
      stubBinding.tvTestMe.text = "Hurray"
   }
}
```

Comment: Where does "by autoCleared" come from?

Comment: @Andrew You can find it on Google's [Github browser sample](https://github.com/sockeqwe/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/AutoClearedValue.java)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Question: What about two-way-databinding in viewstub? How does that work. Normal "@={text}" is not working

Comment: @Andrew I don't use data-binding... So I can't answer that. Sorry!

Comment: Isn't the reason for stubs to dynamically be able to switch layouts, for example if you want to decide which layout to inflate into the stub based on a typed variable? The above approach locks you in due to the type of the `stubBinding` variable having to match the layout I inflate, doesn't it? Is there a way to not depend on the included layout directly (assuming the IDs in both possible layouts are the same) and to be able to access the included layout through a `stubBinding` variable that supports two layouts?

Comment: @Somesh Kumar I am trying to set up ViewBinding with a ViewStub, using Android code here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77975360/android-how-to-convert-viewstub-code-for-viewbinding  I don't know Kotlin so I would appreciate any insights or ideas you have for conversion using Android.

Answer (score 4):

One small correction in @Somesh's answer

The inflated view which is passed to the StubBinding is wrong. We should actually pass the view which we receive from the `onInflate` listener

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
private var binding: FragmentMainBinding by autoCleared()
private var stubBinding: StubBinding by autoCleared()

  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
      binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
      binding.stub.setOnInflateListener { _, inflated -> stubBinding = StubBinding.bind(inflated) }
      return binding.root
  }

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
      binding.stub.inflate()
      stubBinding.tvTestMe.text = "Hurray"
   }
}
```

Comment: Original answer has been edited to fix this

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via 2 simple lines

```
binding.viewStub.layoutResource = R.layout.layoutId
binding.viewStub.inflate()
```

Comment: This answer is missing an important line of code: Binding of the stub. `stubBinding = StubBinding.bind(inflated)` where `inflated` is the view returned from line 2.